# AutoMapper Map all properties based on other model property value

Tags: c#, .net, mapping, automapper

I have the following scenario :

Source class :

```
   public class Source
    {
      public int? A { get; set; }

      public int? B { get; set; }

      public int? C { get; set; }
    }
```

Destination class :

```
 public class Destination
    {
        public int A { get; set; }

        public bool AIsNull { get; set; }

        public int B { get; set; }

        public bool BIsNull { get; set; }

        public int C { get; set; }

        public bool CIsNull { get; set; }
    }
```

I would like to obtain a mapping from Source => Destion  in the following manner as following :

- try to set the destination property with the associated source property (this it can be done using a Converter( implementing ITypeConverter)
- after the property is set, I want to set the destination associated IsNull property based on the nullable source property.

EDIT, after some research :

```
  class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var srcClass = new SourceClass { Value1 = 10, Value2 = null, Value3 = 20 };

        Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.ClearPrefixes();
            cfg.RecognizePostfixes("IsNull");
            cfg.CreateMap<SourceClass, TargetClass>();
        });

        var targetClass = Mapper.Map<SourceClass, TargetClass>(srcClass);

    }
}

public class SourceClass
{
    public int? Value1 { get; set; }
    public int? Value2 { get; set; }
    public int? Value3 { get; set; }
}

public class TargetClass
{
    public bool Value1IsNull { get; set; }
    public bool Value2IsNull { get; set; }
    public bool Value3IsNull { get; set; }
}
```

and still, the magic does not happen for this case

Comment: RecognizeDestinationPostfixes should help you map the IsNull properties.

Comment: it's not helping a lot, or I dont know how to use this. I'm saying this because I have the IsNull properties only to the destination model.

Comment: http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Configuration.html?#recognizing-pre-postfixes

Comment: please have a look at my scenario, it's different

Comment: No, actually is quite similar, you just need to think things over. Browse the relevant tests in the AM repo.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu please find my edit ... and let me know what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this should work, I have not tested this in VS so use with a grain of salt.

```
var map = CreateMap<Source,Target>();

map.ForAllMembers(opt => opt.Ignore());

map.ForMember(dest => dest.A, opt => opt.MapFrom( src => src.A.HasValue ? src.A.Value : 0));

map.ForMember(dest => dest.AIsNull, opt => opt.MapFrom( src => src.A.HasValue ? true : false));
```

Comment: I see your point, and I think is something that I'm looking for ... but what is I have 100 properties for instance ? is there a way to map all in a generic way ?